# How to render XML file using CodeBehind C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, code-behind

I wanted to know how can I get request to XML file (.xml) but to render the response using codebehind... (like doing <% ... %> )

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests to ASP.NET applications that return XML or other non-HTML responses are best implemented as handlers (*.ASHX).  You can find an example of how to do this here:

http://www.aspcode.net/Creating-an-ASHX-handler-in-ASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand the question, but you seem to ask about something like

```
<%
  Response.Clear();
  Response.ContentType="text/xml";

  Response.Write("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"">");
  Response.Write("<MyFancyRecord>");
  Response.Write("<Title>" + someRec.Title + "</Title>");
  Response.Write("<Price>" + (someRec.Price * 1.20) + "</Price>");
  // etc.
  Response.Write("</MyFancyRecord>");

  Response.End();
%>
```

As hinted in other response, while this approach is a direct answer to the OP's question, it is typically better to map non-html requests to handlers.

Comment: But how can I create a page that doesnt send HTML?

Comment: using exactly the posted code - you will be sending XML per the content type setting...

Comment: @oshafran:  the `Response.ContentType` is what does it. This property of the Response object translates to the [HTTP] header property named "Content-Type" which in turn instructs the receiving web client that this is not the usual html fare, but some other content, here, a "plain" XML file.

Comment: will the IIS know how to handle this if xml extension is requested?

Comment: This code might not work unless you clear the response buffer first. There may be some artifacts from the ASPX page above the XML signature.